# How to check allowed file extensions for multimedia component (with CoreService)?

Tags: core-service

I want to replace the jpg file of a multimedia component with a file with another extension (png for example). How can I check if the file extension is allowed for the component schema?
I already got the MultimediaTypeData of the new extension:

```
string extension = "png";
var list = m_client.GetSystemWideList(new MultimediaTypesFilterData());
var multimediaType = list.OfType<MultimediaTypeData>().FirstOrDefault(mt => mt.FileExtensions.Contains(extension, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

With it, I can build LinkToMultimediaTypeData:

```
new LinkToMultimediaTypeData{ IdRef = multimediaType.Id };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you need to use `schema.AllowedMultimediaTypes` property of the SchemaData object.

1. Get the schema of the component you want to update and cast it to `SchemaData` object.
2. Get allowed multimedia types for that schema using `schema.AllowedMultimediaTypes`.
3. Put a condition to check if the new multimedia file is allowed, before updating the component.

Below is the example code:

```
            string componentToUpdateId = "tcm:7-5248";
            string mmExtensionIdToCheck = "tcm:0-1-65544";

            var item = client.Read(componentToUpdateId, new ReadOptions());
            var comp = item as ComponentData;
            var schema = client.Read(comp.Schema.IdRef, new ReadOptions()) as SchemaData;
            if (schema.AllowedMultimediaTypes.Any(t => t.IdRef == mmExtensionIdToCheck))
            {
              // Update the component
            }
```

Hope this helps.